# Is it possible to backup Whatsapp Contact Photos?

Tags: contacts, backup, whatsapp-messenger, contact-photo

As the title says, is it possible to backup my Whatsapp contacts pictures?

I'm not talking about pictures and photos shared between us, I'm referring to the contacts' profile pictures.

All the solutions that I have found are focused on backing up chat histories, shared pictures and so on, but nothing that can perform this task.

Comment: The pictures are located at /Whatsapp/Profile Pictures/. Can't you just copy them with a file Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct button to do this work. But, you can find all those profile pictures that you see in full clear view. These pictures are downloaded in folder **WhatsApp/Profile Pictures**.

From there you can copy and paste where you want. Generally, these will not show in Gallery, because these pictures kept hidden by *.nomedia* file.

Comment: Thanks, I knew where they are located, I was looking for a way to automatically backup them; I guess that I have to do that manually.

Comment: Where you want to automatically backup these pictures?

Comment: @Sekhemty auto backup is not supported AFAIK. Reason...this is what I think!! Just Imagine this:  You have 1000+ contacts. Hundreds of them changing their profile pics regularly and Whatsapp is taking their back up as soon as profile pics changes. As you may know, these back ups are local + Google Drive(optional, as not all user have Google account ), and soon your local storage will become full. Bad user experience...isn't it?